# Host Solr 5.3 using tomcat in windows box

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

Steps to Host Solr 5.3 in Tomcat Server in windows box. 
i am able to host Solr 4.7 but there are few files missing in 5.3 so unable to host it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer a supported configuration. So, even if it worked, there might be issues later. The strong recommendation is to use the server solution that Solr comes with out of the box.